# Travelling to ICLR in Vienna, Austria from India. Confusion about walk-ins

Tags: schengen, schengen-visas, business-travel, austria, conferences

I am a PhD student from India. My work was accepted at [ICLR 2024](https://iclr.cc) conference which will be held in Vienna, Austria from 7 May 2024 to 11 May 2024.  I have two questions.

---

### Q1

I have to apply for a Schengen Visa (Type C: Short-stay) from Austria. I applied for the Visa through VFS Global's [website](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/ind/en/aut). From this website, I could select a sub-type of the Type C Visa, from which I selected "Business". The date of the appointment I got is 8 April 2024. Which is a bit too close to my travel date for comfort. VFS Global however told me on multiple occasions (on email, and phone call), that I can just walk-in without a prior appointment to the embassy in case I'm applying for a business Visa.

Now, I haven't had any communication with the Austrian Embassy itself. Can somebody with previous experience of a similar kind let me know if the embassies and their diplomats allow such walk-ins without date of appointment and if this is allowed, why's the appointment even given of such a later date? It's all giving me a lot of anxiety.

---

### Q2

I have planned to visit Italy since I have some leaves that I can use. My number of days of stay in Italy are more than number of days I'll stay in Austria. But my *main destination* is still the conference which provides me a letter of invitation (thus applying for "Business" visa). I have heard from people that even then the embassy and their diplomats make a fuss about the number of days spent in Austria being less than the number of days spent elsewhere. But as far as I know, Schengen universal visa rules have two things mentioned in their article to define the main destination: (1) state in whose territory the maximum days are spent, (2) the destination of the main purpose of the visit.

So, I should get a "Business" Visa from Austria due to (2). Or am I wrong with this? Again, if anyone with experience could ease my anxiety.
P.S.: I did email the Austrian Embassy regarding this, however I have not gotten any response from them as of now.

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The duration of stay in each state is the secondary rule, to be used only if there isn't a clear main destination.  This aspect of your question is probably a duplicate, so you might want to remove it (or ask it separately if you can't find s duplicate question on the site).

Comment: @phoog we have seen questions here where VFS or other intermediary insisted that the number of days had to be greater for the country of application (even if this is contrary to the rules).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Now, I haven't had any communication with the Austrian Embassy itself

You won't have any, VFSGlobal is a subcontractor responsible for customer facing actions regarding visas (Visa Facilitation services).

You will never need go to the embassy nor have any contacts with them under normal circumstances, you will go to the VFS Global office and drop your application there

> Can somebody with previous experience of a similar kind let me know if the embassies and their diplomats allow such walk-ins without date of appointment

If the processor (VFS Global) told you you can walk in, then you can just walk in, they're a private business, what they decide about how your application should be dropped off is their choice.